# what are the other usage of word "been" in english?

Tags: grammar, american-english

I have heard usage of "been" other that in perfect continuous tense.

like when we are talking about past, could we say that "I been given some work"?

is the above sentence correct? if not why?

but, this sentence convince me, because it is the situation in which i am talking about past and some thing happened on me, so in order to say that i need to use forms of "be", but i cannot say in perfect form because "have " and "had" is not form of "be", but if i use "have been" or "had been" then it will be in perfect continuous, again i don't want to add continuous sense to it, it should be in perfect with 3rd form of verb.

am i correct?

Comment: I don’t really understand the paragraph you’ve added to the question. Can you provide the broader context of the sentence, since you seem to think that in the broader context you shouldn’t use a form of “have”

Comment: @oerkelens are you saying that "i have been given some work" is correct?

Comment: and about learning English, i have read all the grammar book in my house. because i heard it in anime, i asked this question.the problem with us, whose English is 2nd language is that we have to keep in track what is wrong and what is correct no matter ho correct it seems we have to check it before. anyway thanks bros.)

Comment: As long as you actually capitalise the _I_, yes, that sentence is absolutely fine, if you use it in the right situation. But that is true for any sentence.

Answer (score 1):

That usage is not correct. There is no tense where you can just use “been” by itself, it always follows a form of the verb “to have”.

In the US, “I been given” can be used as slang, but that use is stereotypical of poorly educated people and widely avoided.

Comment: but, i have heard it while watching anime, and it feels right, it is the situation when some one is telling about the past and dont want to add continuous sense to it, because whole story is already in perfect continuous.

Comment: considering i am saying in indirect speech?

Comment: @Rahul I’ve edited my answer to include the only usage along these lines I’m aware of. I don’t think that the construction you’re discussing is correct.

Comment: please read my edited question and respond.

Comment: man, i have never seen down vote in question for learning language!

Comment: Hello, Stella. Do you really think that answering questions at this level is appropriate on a website devoted to linguists?

Answer (score 1):

"I have been given some work" can be contracted to "I've been given some work."

The *'ve* part of contractions can often be very quiet when spoken quickly or not enunciated perfectly, and in certain varieties and dynamics of English slang, it can be omitted entirely, particularly if *been* is emphasized loudly.

It's always supposed to be there, though.  "I been gone" and "I have been gone" don't mean different things, for example, so there is no additional use or tense available with *been*.